# Semaphore - Showing it is always true that S >= 0

Tags: process, operating-system, semaphore

I was reading online about Semaphores and I found this question that I found really interesting where I need to show that:

```
For any semaphore S, it is always true that S >= 0
```

I am having trouble trying to understand how I could do that?

From what I have read online this statement is true but what I find difficult understanding is why?

Would anyone be able to shed some light?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semaphore_(programming)#Semantics_and_implementation

Comment: It's in the spec ^^^^.  The internal unit count is not exposed by a semahore - it only supports signal and wait methods.   A function to return the count would be of limited use since the result would be stale when returned.